# How to remove white line?

Tags: css, line

I have this weird white line on my front page that wont be removed. I loocked and cant find what it is. the site is responsive and it looks even weirder on on the cellphone. Can someone help me?

Comment: You think im going to inspect your page? Provide code

Comment: which blank line? Please write in the question the minimal code to reproduce the issue otherwise the question will be outdated/useless if you change your webiste

Comment: Website not loading...

Comment: I dont know what code to provide, then i would have provided right?

Comment: The website is slow, but working.  the white line between my two images in the header. the line is under my menu.

Comment: Crikey is that website running on a calculator? I think you've got bigger issues than a white line...

Comment: dont know what a calculator is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you have a couple issues.  The quickest and easiest fix is to update the css class 
gdlr-header-inner 
add background-color:transparent;

That is the first issue is the background is white.

The next fix I would do as an easy fix is to look at the div right after the closeing header tag it should have the class content-wrapper.

To that div I would add margin-top:-95px;

At the end of the day the issue is your header is larger then the top part of the image.  I wonder if you should merge the two images and set the background color and the background image to the body tag.  Then you wouldn't have to worry about it.  You then could still push the top down x pixels
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp

Comment: I made  it transperent and it worked! but the the site is resonsive so when i resize the window it keeps comming back. And now i got a white spaceunder the picture and the shadow.

Comment: that would be another reason why I would do it as a background image on the body.  The other option would be created a div element and give it an absolute position of 0 and 0 and give it a fixed height and then set the width to 100%;  Then you could put an image tag inside of that div and set the width to 100% which should then resize the image as the page changes.  Then you could also change the background image depending on the media queries for the responsive design.  But doing it like you are doing the problem is because the header needs the room for the logo you have to work around that.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, the div your logo is in along with its padding are too big for the header.
So it's pushing the rest of the page down.

Try changing the top and bottom padding on the gdlr-logo div.

Comment: thank you! Even if i change it its still i little white line. I tried using zindex so the logo would be over but dident get it to work. Is is totaly impossible to get the picture to line?

Comment: I'm not sure you mean z-index. I think you mean position: absolute;
Try adding that to the gdlr-logo div

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with the height of some elements, like:

```
.gdlr-logo {margin-top: 26px;}
```

Try to remove some margins and review the height of elements on the header.

Comment: I did this and it worked a bit. even set the background in the header to transperent. But the site is responsive so the line appers as soon as i change the size of the window.